# How to access an element in a 3D matrix in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix `A` in MATLAB. To access the element `(i,j)`, I can simply wirte `A(i, j)`. Now how to access the element `(i, j)` in 3-D matrix?

```
M = 4;
N = 4;
D = 2;
A = rand(M, N, D);
```

I write `A(:, :, 1)(i, j)` but it gives me an error. Also I tried by chance `A(i, j)` but it gives me the `(i, j)` element of `A(:, :, 1)`.

Comment: With a third dimension, you now have depth, so you need to specify what layer you want the (i,j)th element from. There is not a singular (i,j) element.

Comment: In other words, for your example `A(i, j, :)` is a vector of two elements.

Comment: Ah ok. Thanks. So if I want `A(i, j)` of the first matrix, I can write `A(i, j, 1)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is easy:

- To access the element `(i, j)` of a 3D matrix, you do the following:

  ```
  A(i, j, k); % element (i, j) of the matrix number k.
  ```